# Push Notifications for Swift iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, notifications, ios10

I'm struggling to get push notifications to work with Swift with iOS 10.  Registering seems to be going through successfully, but creating a notificaiton does nothing on the device and returns a nil error.  Any ideas what I'm missing?

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
class SPKPushNotifications
{
    class func register(application:UIApplication){
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]) { (granted, error) in
                // Enable or disable features based on authorization.
                application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
            }
        } else {
            let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [UIUserNotificationType.alert, UIUserNotificationType.badge, UIUserNotificationType.sound]
            let pushNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: notificationTypes, categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotificationSettings)
            application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }
    class func unregister(application:UIApplication){
        application.unregisterForRemoteNotifications()
    }
    class func create(title:String, body:String, delay:Double, repeats:Bool){
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
            content.title = title
            content.body = body
            content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default() //idk if we're gonna want something else
            content.badge = NSNumber(value:UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber+1)
            let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval:delay, repeats:repeats)
            let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier:title, content:content, trigger:trigger)
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.add(request){ (error) in
                print(error)
            }

        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
    class func delete(){
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
            center.removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't see the notification if the application is in the foreground. Try adding the request to the notification center when the application is in the background.

You can do (for this test only) that by adding a few second sleep and moving your application to the background. Or scheduling the notification to a later time when the application is not running in the foreground.

Comment: Delaying it for 10 seconds doesn't work.  Is there a way to move an app to the background with code?

Comment: Ok, so I can move the app to the background with `UIApplication.shared.perform(#selector(URLSessionTask.suspend))`, and the notification shows up.  But I don't want to move the app to the background.  I want it to stay open while the notification is added.

Comment: You can move the application to the background on a device by clicking on the home button, in simulator you can use Hardware->Home.

The notifications are meant to be visible to users if you application is not on the foreground. If you application is in the foreground why do you need so notify them by notification, you can use the UI in the application. Maybe you can elaborate more on your use case. But that seems to be another question, since your push notification are now working.